# Is there a difference between "in review" and "under review"

Tags: management

I recently submitted a paper to a Management journal, usually if the manuscript is in the review process, it shows "under review".

This time, once upon submission the status turned "in review". I wonder why it turned like this right away and anyone has any idea if there is actually a difference?

Answer (score 1):

A wild guess, but since you just submitted it, maybe it means that the editor/staff is checking to see if the paper fits the theme of the journal.

Answer (score 1):

From the perspective of English language and common usage, there's no significant difference between "in review" and "under review."

From your question, I'm not clear on whether your comparison is between two different papers or if you saw the status change from "in" to "under" on a single submission.

- If the former, then ignore it, they're equivalent.
- If the latter, then probably the paper has moved from one (of the many) internal stage in the paper processing chain to another.  I suspect the system was likely not supposed to make this evident, but has accidentally exposed state change information because the two states were accidentally labelled with the different equivalent statements.

Comment: Thanks, no I didnt see the status change in the same submission. I was talking from my previous experience with this journal that when I submit a paper it goes in the review process as "under review". What worries me is not really the difference, as it is the fact that once I submitted the paper it went automatically "in review".